# What is .Net RxTx

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, rxtx

My boss just sent me some links talking about using `RxTx` in .Net.

That's it! I immediately thought, *"what the hell is RxTx?"*.

I've had a quick look about and it appears to be some kind of pattern used in Java.

Can someone, **briefly**, explain what the RxTx pattern is (from a .Net perspective)?

Comment: and the downvotes for?

Comment: Perhaps you could reword your question a bit and show your research, as for now the first answer that comes to mind is _"ask your boss what he means with his email"_.

Comment: Also, not sure why you think the examples are in Java - there's definitely references to the `System.` namespaces, the use of Linq, etc.

Comment: I could, but what's wrong with asking what RxTx is on .Net? Someone else may well want to know this? Therefore I'm contributing to the SO community? No?

Comment: I don't think the links are in Java, they are in .Net. RxTx seems to be some pattern I've never heard of. That is the main question. Let me try and rephrase.

Comment: I think people are downvoting because stackoverflow is a questions and answers site dealing with answers to specific programming questions. Basically, most users expect a Question OP to post code which can enable them to reproduce the problem he is having. Some are more zealous than others in enforcing the suitability of questions.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Why would I post code to a patterns question? This is exactly why the close votes about adding code were removed. [Not every question has to include code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort/210928#210928).

Comment: I did not downvote, just trying to explain the reasoning of some users. I don't agree with them or anything

Comment: Didn't intend that to be solely aimed at you @BolucPapuccuoglu, the whole *you've not added any code therefore it must be a bad question* thing bugs me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rx** stands for [.NET Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609), linked from your [second link](http://tx.codeplex.com/):

> The Reactive Extensions (Rx)...
>
> ...is a library to compose asynchronous and event-based programs using observable collections and LINQ-style query operators.

[**Tx**](http://tx.codeplex.com/) seems to be an library written on top of Reactive Extensions, which allow you to query and monitor logs:

> [Query] as if all the events were in a database, except no database is involved, the query happens directly on raw logs/traces or real-time sessions

---

Your confusion with Java seems to come from searching the web on `RXTX`, which is a [serial and parallel communications library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rxtx), not really relevant to the subject at hand. :-)